# Using SWI-Prolog Interactively - Output Taken off

Tags: prolog, interactive-mode

I'm using SWI-Prolog interactively. When I run my query, I get a prefix of the output and the rest is taken off (marked using the string `...|...`). Is this normal or should I go back and fix my program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing to worry about. It's just abbreviating it visually... just press 'w' (write) to display the complete internal representation of the list.

Answer (score 3):

The number of items shown is controlled by a prolog flag.
You can remove it by issuing

```
remove_max_depth:-
    current_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options,Options), 
    select(max_depth(_), Options, NOptions)->
    set_prolog_flag(toplevel_print_options, NOptions); true.
```