# How do you save all possible solutions in SWI-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have this predicate that has about a thousand possibilities and I need all possibilities as an output. It is not possible to simply copy and paste all listed possibilities in SWI-Prolog on Windows since you can only scroll up so much.

My predicate looks like this:

```
?- question(X,Y,Z).
X = 'Fo',
Y = 'Ob',
Z = 'Ar' ;
X = 'Fo2',
etc...
```

I was wondering if there was a way to save the result in a file or something?

Comment: As beginner, I'd recommend you look first at other issues. You inherently need some side effects here, and side-effects will not help you understand the essence of Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
main :-
    tell('output.txt'),
    (
        question(X,Y,Z),
        writeln([X, Y, Z]),
        fail
    ;
        told
    ).
```

Or you can run the query `( question(X,Y,Z),  writeln([X, Y, Z]), fail ; true ).` in Prolog and get all solutions at standard output (screen).

Comment: Where would the output.txt be generated? It is not in the directory of my .PL

Comment: I've corrected the code after testing in SWI-Prolog: file must be explicitly closed (`told`).

Comment: Once again, I can't find the output.txt file.

Comment: Did you reload the updated code in Prolog?
And you did run `main.` in Prolog, right?

Comment: Yes and yes. I have a feeling I'm not looking at the right place. Perhaps it is generating in another directory?

Comment: See my answer updated, you can get all solutions on the screen and then copy-paste to some file.

Comment: ...which comes back to my original problem, which is that the console itself does not list all possibilities, so copy-pasting is not an option. Oh well, thanks anyway.

Comment: The output file is generated in current working directory.
You can change it with `cd('directory-path-here').`

Comment: Or you can specify not just 'output.txt', but a full path like '/home/user/output.txt' or 'C:\output.txt'

Comment: -1: tell/told is from the 1970s. Use open/3, close/1 instead. Also using writeln is not a good idea: You cannot always read terms back. Instead, use writeq/1

Answer (score 3):

Use findall/3:

```
findall([X,Y,Z],question(X,Y,Z),R).
```

R shall be bound to the list of all [X,Y,Z] such that question(X,Y,Z) succeeds.

For more information see: [Documentatin on Findall](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Prolog/Bagof,_Setof_and_Findall)

Comment: This does not list all possibilities. It lists some then writes "..." and closes the list. I need all of them.

Comment: @MartinCousineau: joaoraf is right. The ... are only printed by the toplevel. You can even switch them off.

Answer (score 0):

SWI-Prolog offers a way to save the interaction carried on the REPL (Read,Eval,Print,Loop) console: see the [protocol](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.37%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/protocol.html%27%29%29) builtins. This way variables names are retained. Beware, the output could be difficult to process, and long variables will be replaced by ellipsis (you can change this, see [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252431/using-swi-prolog-interactively-output-taken-off)).

Otherwise, [forall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2)/2 could be a viable alternative

```
?- open('a.txt',write,S), forall(member(X,[martin,carlo]), format(S,'~q~n',[X])), close(S).
```